# Disable all shortcuts in a text box

Tags: winforms, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I am aware of the shortcuts enabled property, however, It does not disable all shortcuts.

For example, zooming with ctrl+mousewheel or writing superscript letters with ctrl+shift+plus.

If you're giving me a solution that disables shortcuts by their name, id, keys, etc., please give me a list of *all* the shortcuts and their names, ids, keys etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!
To handle a key press by myself without letting the form handle it simply:

```
void OnRichTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Why Would I ever Want to Write Superscript Letters?!");
         e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

Now [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#rich_edit_shortcut_keys) is a list of all the shortcuts coming with a rich text box, although, I tried some of them out and they didn't work, so you got to check first.